# Pancake/Uniswap: tell inside contract if a transfer is a buy or sell

Tags: uniswap, transfer, pancakeswap

I have a token contract that will exclusively use Pancakeswap as trading platform.
How can I tell in the contract if a transfer represents someone buying the token or someone selling it?

Answer (score 0):

You can check `msg.sender` in `transferFrom()`.

Comment: How though? I see that contracts interact with a router, but sometimes the're a middleman inbetween (wallet -> middleman -> router)